# Is it possible to export, save, or find the Esri locator files for a geocoding service running on ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, geocoding, arcgis-enterprise

I have a geocoding service running fine on an ArcGIS Server 10.4.1 machine, it was created years ago and its origins are unknown to me. I do have admin rights on the server. I need to recreate this geocoding service on a new 10.7.1 site. In order to do that, I need the locator files (.LOC file, etc.) used by the current geocoding service. Is there a way to save or export those files using the service, or at least a way to examine the service and, somewhere in its details or properties, find the path where the locator files used by the service are stored? There is no useful information in the service's Item Description or other metadata.

If this were a map service, I could look in Service Properties > Parameters and the Original Document field would tell me the path to the .MXD that was used to create the service. But there doesn't appear to be any equivalent for a geocoding service: There's no way to look at the geocoding service properties and find the path to the locator files it's using.

Comment: It should be able to via ArcCatalog https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/geocoding/copying-and-pasting-an-address-locator-in-arccatalog.htm (Note ArcGIS 10.4 is the last release to support storing locators in geodatabases.)

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks, that helps: I did find that this locator was stored in a geodatabase, but when I browsed the GDB using ArcCatalog, it couldn't find it, because I'm using ArcCatalog 10.7.1. With 10.4.1, I can see and copy the locator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this on the [esri forums](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-questions/is-it-possible-to-export-save-or-otherwise-find-the-esri-locator/m-p/1044369#M29904). It is not possible to find or export the locator files if you only have access to the service's REST endpoint, but you **can** find them if you have access to the ArcGIS Server's `config-store` folder. Open the file `\config-store\services\<service name>\esriinfo\manifest\manifest.json` file and you'll find the path to the locator, which you can then use to retrieve or export the .LOC and other files you need to examine or recreate the locator.

Also, as Mapperz pointed out in a comment, ArcGIS 10.4.1 is the last version which supported locators in geodatabases. So if your old locator is running in a GDB, you won't be able to export it (or even see it) in a later ArcGIS Desktop version.